# История экземпляров моделей django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, history

Необходимо для экземпляров моделей иметь историю, чтобы была возможность показать пользователю старые значения полей, да и некоторые удаленные объекты. Смотрел в сторону django-simple-history, но там для полей отношения сохраняются только id, а саму связь удаляют, чтобы, как я понял, не возникло ситуации, когда экземпляр модели А - живой, а экземпляр модели B, который имеет ссылку на A, исторический и при удалении A каскадно не удалился исторический B ([ответ автора библиотеки](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues/682)). Дело в том, что когда необходимо показывать удаленные объекты через djangorestframework, то я предполагаю, что в сериализаторе исторических моделей (ибо экземпляр А и историческая версия экземпляра А - это разные модели) нужно будет переопределять поле каждой связи, чтобы вытаскивать и отдавать связанные объекты. А если к этому прикинуть, что у каждого связанного объекта тоже есть связи, которые нужно отображать, если пользователь захочет к нему перейти, то, как паутина, все связи надо переопределять. Это не выглядит удобно. Может быть есть какой-то другой путь работать с историческими объектами в drf?

Comment: https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev здесь в исторических моделях хранится информация о том, 1) был ли от отредактирован или удален; 2) работают ли связи из коробки?

Comment: А так же хранится, что и как была изменено. Вся история значений для каждого поля. Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под "работаю связи". В моделях Django связи и хранятся в виде внешних ключей - идентификаторов тех записей в БД, на которые связь ссылается.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev <что вы имеете ввиду под "работаю связи">:  в simple-history при работе с объектом из истории при обращении к связанному объекту(значит поле связи OtO, FK или MtM) я не получу связанный объект (он бы, например, искал его в живых объектах, а если там не нашёл, то в исторических), а получу лишь id объекта. Так же в simple history можно легко отфильтровать и взять все удаленные объекты конкретной модели (ибо они помечены history_type = "-", что значит удалено). А в django-reversion для получения удаленного объекта, как я понял, обязательно нужно иметь pk